# cannot update paperclip image in active admin nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, activeadmin

I have models product and product images. Product_images is a paperclip model. Product has many product_images. I am making an Active Admin form which uploads multiple images and shows these images to the Products view page.

However, when I save the product. The product table is updated, but not the product_image table. Image attaching normally, but I can't update fields of already uploaded image.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :product_images_attributes 
      has_many :product_images, :dependent => :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_images, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['product_image'].nil? }, :allow_destroy => true
end

class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :style
    attr_accessible :image 
    belongs_to :product
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :small => "150x150>", :large => "320x240>" }
    validates_attachment_presence :image
end

ActiveAdmin.register Product do
form :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do
      f.input :name
    end
    f.inputs "Product images" do        
        f.has_many :product_images do |p|
            p.input :style, :as => :select, :collection => Image::STYLES, :include_blank => false
            p.input :image, :as => :file, :label => "Image",:hint => p.object.image.nil? ? p.template.content_tag(:span, "No Image Yet") : p.template.image_tag(p.object.image.url(:small))
            p.input :_destroy, :as=>:boolean, :required => false, :label => 'Remove image'
        end 
    end
    f.buttons
end
```

**UPDATE**

In the products model I do:

```
  after_update :check

  def check
    if ProductImage.find_by_product_id(self.id).changed?
      raise "image"
    else
      raise "fail"
    end   
  end
```

and it's alway raise "fail"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure `ActiveRecord` to cascade-save changes to items in a collection for a model by adding the `:autosave => true` option when declaring the association.

Try:

```
 has_many :product_images, :dependent => :destroy, :autosave => true
```

Also, you can save the table data on association in the `after_save` callback like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :product_images_attributes 
      has_many :product_images, :dependent => :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_images, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['product_image'].nil? }, :allow_destroy => true

       after_save :do_product_image_update

private
    def do_product_image_update
       self.product_images.save
    end

end
```

Comment: I can change the attachment image, but I can't change style of attachment.

Comment: Nope, even if I do `after_update` callback with raising some exception in my ProductImage model, it doesn't raise.

Comment: do you have `product_id` field in `ProductImage` table? If so, can you give the exception details in a `after_update` callback?

Comment: Yes, I have this foreign key. In this callback I simply do `raise "image updated!!!"`, but it never happens.

Comment: It seems that new values from active admin's inputs can't be passed to ProductImage object.

Comment: do you want to say that `after_update` callback is not happening because `raise "image updated!!!` is not raising any exception ?

Comment: then probably you are saving the `products` table records and not updating or else debug with different `filter` options in a `products` model that what's causing the callback not being called.

Comment: then you are wrong. Your update is telling that `after_update` is getting called but the condition inside it that is checking the image change is not met so you are getting `fail`.

Comment: But I have changed input value (style) in active admin form before submit it.

Comment: check if you update other fields, then does the corresponding associated table fields get updated or not? Also, do input value field for style gets updated in products table?

Comment: Fields of product table gets updated successfully, all works fine, except attachment fields (style field) update.

Comment: so you yourself told that where the actual problem is. Because the style field is never updating, the condition `if ProductImage.find_by_product_id(self.id).changed?` is getting false. So you are getting `raise fail`.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error using rails 4.1. Just solved this. 
I noticed that warnings in my output:

```
Unpermitted parameters: _destroy, id
Unpermitted parameters: _destroy, id
Unpermitted parameters: _destroy, id
```

So I just passed them to permit_params:

`permit_params assets_attributes: [:image, :image_file_name, :image_content_type, :image_file_size, :image_updated_at, :_destroy, :id]`

to AA's resource page. And it worked. 
I hope it will help. 
If not - here is my listings.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do

  permit_params :name, :description, :price, :brand_id, :category_id, assets_attributes: [:image, :image_file_name, :image_content_type, :image_file_size, :image_updated_at, :_destroy, :id]

  form multipart: true do |f|

      f.inputs "Детали" do
        f.input :category_id, as: :select, collection: Category.all, include_blank: false
        f.input :brand_id, as: :select, collection: Brand.all, include_blank: false

        f.input :name
        f.input :description
        f.input :price
      end

      f.inputs 'Фотографии' do
        f.has_many :assets, allow_destroy: true, heading: 'Фото', new_record: false do |fasset|
          fasset.input :image, as: :file, hint: fasset.template.image_tag(fasset.object.image.url(:thumb))
        end
      end
      f.actions
  end

end


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :brand
  has_many :assets, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, allow_destroy: true,
                                :reject_if => lambda { |attributes| attributes[:image].blank? }

  validate :name, presence: true
  validate :description, presence: true
  validate :price, presence: true

end


class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates_with AttachmentPresenceValidator, :attributes => :image

end
```